# How to upgrade Container-Optimized OS (COS) virtual machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have a VM instance with a boot disk which was created using cos-stable-81-12871-119-0 image.

I would like to upgrade the OS to a later LTS version.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Note: All the docker volume data is on the boot disk, I would like to preserve this.

Comment: Edit your question with version details. I am not sure if your image can be updated. images prior to cos-81-12871-1000-0 cannot be updated. Consult this document: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/auto-update

Comment: Agreed it can't be automatically updated. If I manually create a new instance, what is the best way to get my data over to the new disk?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

Comment: I was hoping to minimize the number of manual steps taken, e.g. somehow copying over /mnt/stateful_partition to a new instance. But looks like I will need to do it completely manually.

Thanks for your help @JohnHanley!

Comment: @Himel the COS images are design to run container, not to store data. You are in a corner here because of not perfect design. You should have your COS image, with a minimum free space to pull your container. If you need volume, add another persistent disk to your Compute Engine and store the data in that additional disk. Like that, you are able to kill and recreate your "stateless" part, by keep the stateful persistent disk part

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for the advice, I will split out the data to another disk. I agree the design isn't the greatest, unfortunately it was something I inherited.

Answer (score 1):

As @John Hanley mentioned and also stated in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/auto-update):

The Container-Optimized OS team is actively working on improving our backend infrastructure that makes automatic updates possible. As part of these changes, we are rotating the keys used to sign and validate the update payloads. However, images released before the key rotation cannot be automatically updated to images released after the rotation. The affected list of images are as follows:

These images cannot be updated to the latest versions:

1. On Milestone 77: images prior to cos-77-12371-1000-0
2. On Milestone 81: images prior to **cos-81-12871-1000-0**
3. On Milestone 85: images prior to cos-85-13310-1000-0
4. On Milestone 86: images prior to cos-dev-86-15053-0-0

In these cases, users should manually choose newer OS versions by recreating their VM instances with the newer image. And to get  data over to the new disk refer to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).